# sinon stub first api call and spy second api call

Tags: javascript, fetch, sinon

I have a method like this

```
fetch('first api')
    .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === '500') {
            return Promise.reject('some error');
        }
        return fetch('second api');
     })
     .then(resp => {
         // do something;
     })
     .catch(resp => {
        // do something;
     });
```

I am stubbing the first fetch call like

```
const stub = sinon.stub(window, 'fetch');
```

Now to test success call

```
stub.withArgs('first api').returns(Promise.resolve(//window.Response));
```

or failure

```
stub.withArgs('first api').returns(Promise.reject(//window.Response));
```

Have two questions:

1. How can I `spy` that in case of first api error scenario, second fetch api is not called?
2. How can I stub both fetch calls and test that last `then` is called when both fetch calls is resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spy api on stubs. So if you make a stub of `fetch` you can use all the tools such as `onFirstCall().resolves('some value')` to return a promise as well as the spy properties like `calledTwice`.

For example to return two different promises and test that `fetch` was called twice you can:

```js
function run(){
  return fetch('first api')
    .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === '500') {
            return Promise.reject('some error');
        }
        return fetch('second api');
     })
     .then(resp => {
         // do something;
     })
     .catch(resp => {
        // do something;
     });
}

let stub = sinon.stub(window, 'fetch')
stub.onFirstCall().resolves("testing first")
stub.onSecondCall().resolves("testing second")

run().then(()=> console.log("called twice: ", stub.calledTwice))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/7.1.1/sinon.min.js"></script>
```

To test for rejected promises use `stub.rejects('some values')`